# Change some values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools, cycle

Can you help on the following task? I have a dataframe column such as:

```
index df['Q0']
0         1
1         2
2         3
3         5
4         5
5         6
6         7
7         8
8         3
9         2
10        4
11        7
```

I want to substitute the values in df.loc[3:8,'Q0'] with the values in df.loc[0:2,'Q0'] if df.loc[0,'Q0']!=df.loc[3,'Q0']

The result should look like the one below:

```
index df['Q0']
0         1
1         2
2         3
3         1
4         2
5         3
6         1
7         2
8         3
9         2
10        4
11        7
```

I tried the following line:

```
df.loc[3:8,'Q0'].where(~df.loc[0,'Q0']!=df.loc[3,'Q0']),other=df.loc[0:2,'Q0'],inplace=True)
```

or

```
df['Q0'].replace(to_replace=df.loc[3:8,'Q0'], value=df.loc[0:2,'Q0'], inplace=True)
```

But it doesn't work. Most possible I am doing something wrong.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) function:

```
from itertools import cycle

c = cycle(df["Q0"][0:3])
if df.Q0[0] != df.Q0[3]: 
  df["Q0"][3:8] = [next(c) for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: it is simple if condition, not the question main problem @jezrael

Comment: An explanation of what `cycle` function does would be good.

Comment: it is not about opinions, it is either will fail or will succeed.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters

Comment: @jezrael pls if you feel you have a better answer post it.

Comment: Use `df.loc[3:8,'Q0']` instead `df["Q0"][3:8]`

Comment: and same in all answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I tried the suggestions but I have some issues:

@adnanmuttaleb -
When I applied the function in a dataframe with more than 1 column (e.g. 12x2 or larger) I notice that the value in df.Q0[8] didn't change. Why?

@jezrael -
When I adjust to your suggestion I get the error:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 6
```

When I change the range to 6, I am getting wrong results

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle

data={'Q0':[1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8,3,2,4,7],
      'Q0_New':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

##### version 1

c = cycle(df["Q0"][0:3])
if df.Q0[0] != df.Q0[3]: 
  df['Q0_New'][3:8] = [next(c) for _ in range(5)] 

##### version 2

d = cycle(df.loc[0:3,'Q0'])
if df.Q0[0] != df.Q0[3]: 
  df.loc[3:8,'Q0_New'] = [next(d) for _ in range(6)]
```

Why we have different behaviors and what corrections need to be made?

Thanks once more guys.